# Getting, Setting values using Class name

Tags: c#

I am hoping I don't get a flood of downvotes for this question, but I was wondering if there is a way to use the actual class name, without calling properties, to get and set values. So for example, if I were to have:

```
class Perfume
{
  private string _aroma;
  public string Aroma
  {
   set
   {
    _aroma = value;
   }
  }
}
```

Would there be a way to do:

```
Perfume perfume = new Perfume();
perfume = "Aroma"; // which will set _aroma to "Aroma";
```

?

Comment: You could create a new `Perfume`: `public static implicit operator Perfume(string aroma)
            {
                return new Perfume { Aroma = aroma };
            }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way (that i wouldn't use) is to provide an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) from `string` to `Perfume`:

```
public static implicit operator Perfume(string aroma)
{
    return new Perfume { Aroma = aroma };
}
```

Then this works:

```
Perfume perfume = new Perfume();
perfume = "aroma";
```

But it needs to create a new object which is  rarely desired since it deletes all other properties and also makes the code less readable (the first line is pointless since it creates a throwaway-Perfume).

As an aside, normally an `Aroma` would also be a class with properties instead of a `string`. Another way is to provide an `enum` of available aromas. That increases readability and makes the code more robust.

But maybe you are actually looking for a way to find your perfumes via aroma-name. Then a `Dictionary<string, Perfume>` (or `Dictionary<Aroma, Perfume>`, where `Aroma` is the enum) was more appropriate:

```
Dictionary<string, Perfume> allAromas = new Dictionary<string, Perfume>();
allAromas.Add("Musky", new Perfume{Aroma="Musky"});
allAromas.Add("Putrid", new Perfume{Aroma="Putrid"});
allAromas.Add("Pungent", new Perfume{Aroma="Pungent"});
allAromas.Add("Camphoraceous", new Perfume{Aroma="Camphoraceous"});
allAromas.Add("Pepperminty", new Perfume{Aroma="Pepperminty"});
```

Now you can access a perfume later very fast via aroma-name:

```
Perfume muskyPerfume = allAromas["Musky"];
```

Comment: Well, I guess it's interesting it can be done! Probably won't be useful to create a new object when you do a get instead of a set using this method, though, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

There is the standard way of setting details.

```
Perfume perform = new Perfume(){ Aroma = "aroma" };
```

Or via constructor injection if you add a new constructor, which is fairly standard.

```
Perfume perfume = new Perfume("Aroma");

public class Perfume
{
    public string Aroma { get; set; }

    public Perfume(string aroma)
    {
        Aroma = aroma;
    }
}
```